# Tkinter - Create dynamic entrys widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I cannot find a solution to the following problem. Given is a tkinter application with 4 entry widgets `a`,`b`,`c`, and `d` that must fulfill the following conditions:

Only numbers may be entered in entry `a` and there must not be more than 4 digits

If `a` is empty then no input can be made in `c`. The contents of `c` and `d` are the same as `b`.

If `a` is not empty then an entry can be made in `c`. The content of `c` and `d` is the same (they are unlinked from `b`).

The current solutions works only partially. It is able to link entry `b` and `c` and unlink them. But I don't know how to include the 3 condition.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")


def only_numeric_input(P):
    if len(P) > 0 and P.isdigit():
        # enable entry_c and unlink its content from entry_b
        entry_c.config(textvariable=" ", state='normal')
    else:
        # disable entry_c
        entry_c.config(textvariable=var_b, state='disabled')

    if len(P) > 4:
        return False
    # checks if entry's value is an integer or empty and returns an appropriate boolean
    if P.isdigit() or P == "":  # if a digit was entered or nothing was entered
        return True
    return False

callback = root.register(only_numeric_input)  # registers a Tcl to Python callback

var_b = StringVar()
var_c = StringVar()

Label(root, text="a").grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = (10,0))
Label(root, text="b").grid(row = 1, column = 0)
Label(root, text="c").grid(row = 2, column = 0)
Label(root, text="d").grid(row = 3, column = 0, pady = (40,0))

entry_a = Entry(root)
entry_b = Entry(root, textvariable = var_b)
entry_c = Entry(root, textvariable = var_b, state = "disabled")
entry_d = Entry(root, textvariable = var_b)

#display entrys
entry_a.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
entry_b.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
entry_c.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
entry_d.grid(row = 3, column = 1, pady = (40,0))

entry_a.configure(validate="key", validatecommand=(callback, "%P"))  # enables validation

mainloop()
```

Comment: You really aren't wanting to do what I would call dynamic `Entry`s — it sounds to me that you want to do validation of what is being entered into them. The good news is tkinter `Entry` widgets support validation. Here's some slightly dated [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524022302id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html) (I suspect you may be able to find other sources now that you now know what term to look for).

Comment: @martineau will validation be helpful if you want to enter the digits into entrybox and check weather each digit is correct, without using a button?

Comment: Yes, because you can set validation up so that every `'key'` triggers a call to the callback function (as well as various other events mentioned in the documentation).

Comment: @martineau oh thanks ill look up on validation. Micheal, i was asking a Q from my part, as im new to validation, nothing related to this post

Comment: @Michael: Yes, but not with a substitution code that would specify what was being inserted or deleted (which is effectively enables it per keystroke). In other words, the `"%S"` code.

Comment: @matrineau ~ that's true, but they don't need that for this. See my answer.

Comment: @Michael: Perhaps you're right — we'll see if the OP accepts your answer. BTW, you don't need to use `if len(P):`, just plain `if P:` effectively does the same thing in Python.

Comment: @martineau ~ If I understood his instructions properly then my answer works, but even if I didn't, my conditions are correct, it's what's being turned on/off that might be wrong. Good point on `if P:`. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go. You were using `isdigit` for `P` but `%P` is the whole text (including what was just pressed), so we switch to `isnumeric`. If I understood your instructions properly, you forgot to handle `entry_d`.

I used a `range` instead of `len(P) > 0 and len(P) < 5`, and the `range` is correct.

```
def only_numeric_input(P):
    if len(P) in range(1,5) and P.isnumeric():
        #if we have 1 to 4 numeric characters
        # enable entry_c, and unlink entry c & d content from entry b
        entry_c.config(textvariable=var_c, state='normal')
        entry_d.config(textvariable=var_c)
    elif not P:
        #if we have no characters
        # disable entry_c, and link entry c & d content to entry b
        entry_c.config(textvariable=var_b, state='disabled')
        entry_d.config(textvariable=var_b)
    else:
        #everything else
        return False
    
    return True
```

Comment: Sry for the late reply. I just implemented your code and its work perfectly! Thank your very much.